# How to have DBAL's setSQLLogger in symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dbal

I was able to connect to doctrine in symfony2, this way:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                    driver:   "%database_driver%"
                    host:     "%database_host%"
                    port:     "%database_port%"
                    dbname:   "%database_name%"
                    user:     "%database_user%"
                    password: "%database_password%"
                    charset:  UTF8
                    mapping_types:
                                  enum: string

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: false
        proxy_namespace: Proxies
        proxy_dir: Proxies
        default_entity_manager: default # The first defined is used if not set
        entity_managers:
            default:
                    connection: default
                    mappings: # Required
                             ApplicationUserBundle:
                                   type: annotation
                    class_metadata_factory_name: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory
                    dql:
                        datetime_functions:
                        UNIX_TIMESTAMP: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\UnixTimestamp
```

Now my question is that how to have this in configuration above?

$config->setSQLLogger(new Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger());

I mean another way than [this](http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/symfony/logging-doctrine-queries-in-symfony2/). As this is a $config method I guess that should be possible to have it in config.yml, but how?

Answer (score 2):

You need to fill few config parameters

In `doctrine.yaml` config file enable logging

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        logging: true
```

In `services.yaml` config file set logger class

```
services:
    doctrine.dbal.logger:
        class: Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger
```

Do not forget to clean Symfony cache before usage `php bin/console cache:clear`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. `logger.class` is not a valid setting name. [Just `logging` is valid](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/1.12.x/Resources/config/schema/doctrine-1.0.xsd#L37). What you refer to is the [parameter name for the class of the default *dbal* logger service](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/1.12.x/Resources/config/dbal.xml#L10).

Comment: Great, glad it helped! I also tried you suggestions and it works! Yesterday I was trying the opposite: tagging the class as logger, with `Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger: '@doctrine.dbal.logger'`, but it was sorting no effect... – With your edit I managed to make it work (creating a custom *ErrorLogSQLLogger*) thanks! 

Comment: For some reason our Symfony doesn't work this way... the `doctrine:` setting isn't in doctrine.yaml, it's only in the config*.yml files, it doesn't have `logging:` specified, and there's no `doctrine.dbal.logger` specified anywhere, even though the app is calling `setSQLLogger` (where param `logger` is null)... it's such a train wreck trying to figure out how something works in Symfony sometimes.